# Verilog Is this synthesizable read from array

Tags: arrays, verilog, assign, synthesis

Is the following code synthesizable?

```
reg [15:0] litlen_buff0[3:0];
reg [1:0]  rcount0;

assign litlen_buff0_out = litlen_buff0[rcount0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such construct like this is synthezisable if litlen_buff0_out is properly declared as output/inout or signal.

Signal can be used as array index as long as array slice has constant size. For example this code:

```
reg [15:0] litlen_buff0[3:0];
reg [1:0]  rcount0;

assign litlen_buff0_out = litlen_buff0[rcount0 : 0];
```

is not synthezisable because synthesis tool don't know exact size of right hand operand.